# Are QMenus typically in a thread of their own? What's the right way to wait for them to finish handling events?

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qthread, qmenu

In the debugger, I can see that my QMenu objects do not reside in the same thread as the main gui thread.  E.g., `QApplication.instance().thread() == 0xdeadbeef`, but `mymenu.thread() == 0xdeadbabe`

1) Is that expected?  BTW, my QMenus are *not* native menus (I used `setNativeMenuBar(False)`)

2) I want to block until the menu is finished processing all events.  I tried `QApplication.processEvents()`, but that's a little tricky because it has to be called from the *same* thread as the the widget I want to wait for (in my case, the menu).  I used a custom event filter class in combination with `moveToThread()` to make sure that `processEvents()` is called from the same thread that QMenu is running in, but it doesn't seem to matter.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to block for the completion of all QMenu event/action signal handling.  My only option seems to be to `sleep()` long enough that I know the processing is finished.  But that's not really acceptable for my use-case.

Comment: I don't think the debugger is telling you what you think it is--http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Comment: @Matt I think he knows that. He's not saying that the debugger is telling him the *actual* locations are `0xdeadbeef` and `0xdeadbabe`, those are just examples to demonstrate that they are indeed located at two different memory addresses.

Comment: @CodyGray Hmmm, seems like an odd way to go about describing the situation, presumably OP will step in and clear it up.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  CodyGray is correct.  I was merely trying to show that the two threads are not the same by showing that they are at different addresses.  The addresses I gave are not the ones that appeared in the debugger.

Comment: maybe you should instead check where menus are created so that they are in the main thread from the beginning

Comment: I tried : `info("% %u", QApplication::instance()->thread(), menuBar()->thread());` and it returned twice the